# Bringing up the bottom left menu

Tags: interface

Since I generated a landscape, I created some cubes and moved them around. After that, I was trying to adjust the landscape, but the left bottom menu is completely gone. Although I tried Adjust Last Operation, it just showed me the Move option. It totally makes sense because what I did last was moving around the cubes.
Then how do I recall the left bottom menu for the landscape? Or is there another way to adjust it?

Comment: Not possible. Once you do another action, that will become the new last operation.

Comment: Is that mean, I should generate another new landscape? And you can't adjust if you did other operations?
That means you should set everything perfect before you decide to do other operation. That's harsh.

Comment: yes unfortunately, because it is already a finalized mesh.]

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie This is true for the mesh primitives, but not the A.N.T.Landscape

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann oh yeah you're right. I completely forgot

Answer (score -3):

Press the <kbd>N</kbd> key to open the right sidebar menu. You can find the *Create* tab there.